# My load() partially works the first time only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that used to work fine but does not anymore, could anyone point out why?

What should happen is the referenced link gets inserted to target 1 and target 2 is updated with new content from two other sources referenced in the script.

However, on the first clck after the page loads, only target 1 gets updated. On subsequent clicks, the link loads the href item replacing all content on the page.

This is the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>Dynamic Content Page</title>
 <script src="/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <a class="loader" href="php/originalcontent1.php">Load original items</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a class="loader" href="php/newcontent1.php">Load new items</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
   <aside id="target2">
    <?php include 'php/originalcontent3.php' ;?>
    <?php include 'php/originalcontent2.php' ;?>
   </aside>
   <section id="target1">
    <?php include('php/originalcontent1.php') ;?>
   </section>
  </main>   
 </body>
 <script src="/dynamiccontent.js"></script>
</html>
```

and here is the script "dynamiccontent.js:

```
$('.loader').click(function(){
$('.loader').unbind('click');
var url = $(this).attr('href');
$('#target1').load(url);
$('#target2').load(['php/newcontent2.php', 'php/newcontent3.php']);
return false;
});
```

Comment: Since when did [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) accept an array of URLs?

Comment: Andy, I am new to scripting and assumed that it might work. Is there a way to load content from two or more sources?

Comment: Please ignore what @AvinashBabu said as it clearly doesn't have any relation whatsoever.

Comment: look into using `Ajax` as opposed to load and then `append()`ing the result to your target `div`'s

Comment: Rob, will append() remove old content from those target divs too? (I would like to remove old contents when new stuff loads.)

Comment: [append documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/)  Don't fear the docs, they are your best source for the final word.  Append puts at the end.

Comment: Thanks jeremy, I will read the docs on append. What if I matched the contents of my targets (they are only of one type of element) and used .replaceWith([file1,file2])?

Answer (score 2):

I see nowhere in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) that load has a first parameter acceptible as anything other than a URL.

Your code says to stop tracking clicks when any item marked `class="loader"` is clicked.  That's this line:

```
$('.loader').unbind('click');
```

So, subsequent clicks do what they normally would on a link, follow the `href` attribute.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. Apart from my "unbind('click') mistake, when I used load the right way, I was requesting only one file that itself contained two items. Now, I am attempting to call the fragments individually to load into the target. Is there a way that this should be done?

Comment: Call them separately (perhaps loading into two subcontainer-wrappers).